# advanced combinatorics question

Tags: combinatorics

Assume I have a library of $2^{20}$ different books and each book has exactly $2^{20}$ characters in total $2^{40}$ characters. I am only permitted to make 2 modifications. A permitted modification is to insert a character from a-z,A-Z,0-9

Inserting 2 different characters at 2 random positions is straightforward: one has ($2^{40}$$2^{6}$)$^2$=$2^{92}$ possibilities

But what if deleting (1,2,3,...) character(s) before inserting a character at the position where the deletion happened is also permitted? How do I get the total amount possibilities involved?

Comment: Why not try to solve the problem with numbers small enough (instead of all those $2^{20}$) for you to see what's going on and work out the answer? That might give you the idea for solving the problem as stated.

Comment: Hi Gerry already tried,... i will post what I have come up with,...

Answer (score 1):

my problem is the following: The character size changes with each addition or deletion

1. two insertions (no deletions) yields

**$(2^{40}+1)*2^{6}*(2^{40}+2)*2^{6}$**

---

2a. first modification one deletion and insertion, second modification one insertion only

**$(2^{40}+0)*(2^{6}-1)*(2^{40}+1)*2^{6}$**

3a. first modification **two** deletions and insertion, second modification one insertion only

**$(2^{40}-1)*(2^{6}-x)*(2^{40}+0)*2^{6}$**

**Q: x is my first problem is this 0,1 or 2 ???**

4a. first modification **two** deletions and insertion, second modification one insertion only....

---

2b. first modification one **deletion** and insertion, second modification one **deletion** and insertion

**$(2^{40}+0)*(2^{6}-1)*(2^{40}+0)*(2^{6}-1)$**

3b. first modification two **deletions** and insertion, second modification one **deletion** and insertion

**$(2^{40}-1)*(2^{6}-x)*(2^{40}+0)*(2^{6}-y)$**

**Q: again x,y ???**

**Q: Is there a reasonable way to at least estimate with a lower bound the sum of these possibilities if one can make n deletions?**

**UPDATE**

It took me a while, but it was worth it, Gerry's approach made it happen,.. thx

for a rough estimate (more is not need) split the $2^{40}$ into two subsets and compute the possibilities for each set

let n be the character in the given set $2^{39}$
let a be the alphabet count $2^{6}$

The hard way:

1. (n+1)*a
2. (n+0)*(a-1)
3. (n-1)*(a-1)
4. (n-2)*(a-1)

n+2. (n-n)*(a-1)

and so on, sum them up and that's it

The easy way:

just ask the question differently: how many regions are there in text file?

1. we have clearly $2^{39}$ possibilities to select the first position
2. we have $2^{39}-1$ possibilities to select the second position

$(2^{39}*(2^{39}-1)*2^{6})/2$ ≈ $2^{83}$

square to combine both sets ≈ $2^{166}$

is it possible ??? if it's the case then :-)